# Remote TASKKILL not working. User name or Password not correct

Tags: networking, windows-10, passwords, lan

When i run (Win10)

> TASKKILL /s 192.168.1.102 /u USER2 /p  /F ....

I get the error that the username or password is not correct.
I've created a password as before was not existing but still, no luck. 
When trying to access in rdp using the username above written with the password everything works.

For safety (not security) I've disabled both PCs firewall to ensure that some rules were not set right but still nothing to do.
If I ping the remote pc from the main one everything works.

Actually there is a net switch and a router for the internet connection.
How do I fix the issue?
There are no workgroup/domain created. Inside of network sharing everything is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

this is a Remote UAC restrictions, just make some fix in registry.
See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows